# Cannot display image with correct path using ImageIcon

Tags: java, image, swing, user-interface, icons

I've been having an issue with displaying images in Java with the ImageIcon class. The code is very simple, but it simply displays a window like

[image: this].

```
 import javax.swing.*;
 public class TestButtonIcons {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ImageIcon usFlag = new ImageIcon("images/usFlag.png");
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JButton jbt = new JButton(usFlag);
        frame.add(jbt);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

My image is located under the src folder, and my IDE can also detect it, since it shows

[image: this].

Also, if I change the path mentioned above into the full path, like

`"/Users/Mac/Documents/Java TB/ImageIcons/src/images/usFlag.png"`

The program works normally.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ImageIcon(String)` assumes that the image is located on the disk somewhere. When you place the image inside the `src` directory, most IDE's will bundle the image into the resulting Jar (AKA embedded resource), which means that they are no longer a "file" on the disk, but a byte stream in a zip file, so you need to access them differently.

Start by using `ImageIO.read`, unlike `ImageIcon`, it will throw an `IOException` when the image can't be loaded.

You need to use `Class#getResource` or `Class#getResourceAsStream` depending on how need to reference it, for example...

```
BufferedImage image = null;
try {
    image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/usFlag.png"));
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Take a look at [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) for more details

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use "./path" or else it might think it's an absolute path. "." is the current directory, which indicates a relative path instead of an absolute one.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in the location of the image. Place your image in source folder. Try like

```
  JButton button = new JButton();
  try {
    Image img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("images/usFlag.png"));
    button.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
  } catch (IOException ex) {
  }
```

I assume that the image is in `src/images`.

Answer (score 0):

The path you give to the constructor of ImageIcon is relative to the location of your class.
So if your class is org.example.TestButtonIcons it will look for org/example/images/usFlag.png

Hope this helps.